# Laravel 8 passing variables from partial view to parent view

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-blade

I am using laravel 8.74 and I am trying to pass data from a child's view to the parent view guest layout.

The child view is using  tag to inherit the guest view.

This way I was assuming I can use the attributes bag and the @props([]) to get and set the variables to the parent view.

Child or partial view

```
<x-guest-layout :meta_description="$obj->DescriptionToString( 150 )">
```

While the attributes bag does work.

Guest view

```
<x-meta name="description" :content="$attributes->get('meta_description')"/>
```

When using the @props I can only access the variable if it has a default value otherwise, I get “undefined variable.

Guest view

```
@props(["meta_description" => "A description"])
```

It’s so far, the same behavior as a component and that is what I was expecting.

If the @props function exists, then the “meta_description” variable does not exist anymore in the attributes bag, which is normal. But again does not exist if I do not define a default value and the value passed from the child view is overwritten.

Is there something I forgot or misunderstood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dough!!
One of my Beaker moments...

Just realized that the guest and app layouts have class component.

App/View/Components